# How to create a temp directory outside of a test with JUnit 5?

Tags: java, junit, temporary-files, temp

so I like the JUnit 5 feature where you can just write in a test:

```
@TempDir
private Path tempPath;
```

... and JUnit will manage a temporary file for you.

However, this seems to only be working if you use this annotation inside an actual test class. We have, currently, a setup where our custom JUnit extension is using the BeforeAllCallback lifecycle state to generate a temporary directory and backup some local files so we can edit them.

If we use `@TempDir` in there, it's just null. The cause seems to be that `@TempDir` is only supposed to be used in actual test files and there's even a [ticket on GitHub](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/2208) closed regarding that, stating it "works as intended".

I found two possibilies to achieve what we need but I'm not sure if those are correct and how to use them. One is `AnnotationSupport` which seems to be fitting but I can't find examples. One is `TempDirectory` which is used by `TempDir` or uses `TempDir`. But I don't see how I would actually use both.

Or is this just a case where we have to implement this ourselves and/or use some maven package (I don't know any)?

Answer (score 1):

In a similar case we faced, we had to remove the "private" modifier to make it working and having an injected value, as it:

```
@TempDir
Path tempPath;
```

Comment: Interesting. We already implemented our own solution but I would've tried that out. ^^

Comment: With JUnit 5.8 `@TempDir` can be private field too - see [Allow @TempDir fields to be private](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/2687)